# Top border on a LinearLayout with transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a top border to a **LinearLayout** with a transparent background.

The result should be like the following image, where the border is the top border of the "Jp Project" LinearLayout. The background color comes from a FrameLayout who is used as container.

[image]

This is the linear layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menuItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_action"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the style code I am using at the moment:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/base_app_color" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Which draws:
[image]

Have you got any way to fix it just using styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the line should be middle aligned vertically between the Workplaces and Project menu items. I am identifying the Project item as an especial menu item and applying a different layout.

The layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/project_top_line">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_action"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuItemName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The style code is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/base_app_color" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

which draws a line in the middle of the first linear layout.

Answer (score 7):

Set as your LinearLayout background the drawable with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="-2dp" android:bottom="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/borderColor" />
            <solid android:color="@color/backgroundColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nice solution it works perfectly with transparent background!

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need a **blue line** so you can do something like this:

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
```

Comment: It works but I decided to use my solution as simpler to assembly the menu and have got the line middle aligned between Workplaces and Project menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file called border.xml and add this to your layout for making only top border.

```
<item
    android:left="-1dp"
    android:right="-1dp"
    android:bottom="-1dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kellton_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    >
```

Helped for me.